# C# linq - Change the selected field at runtime

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, expression-trees

I have an object Orders (Order, Product, Cost, Price, Client, Day).
I am retrieving a lot of records from the database and to facilitate filtering, I need to pouplate DropDownLists with the distinct values retrieved so the user can select only specific dates or specific products or even a specific price. The IDs of the DropDownList are created as "ddl_" + name of the concerned field.

What I'd like is to be able to define a simple array like this:

```
public string[] filterArray = new string[] { "Order", "Product", "Cost", "Price", "Client", "Day" };
```

Then call a BindDLLs method:

```
foreach (string filterName in filterArray)
{
    // Find the ddl to populate
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)this.FindControl("ddl_" + filterName);
    // Get the data for that ddl only (use filterName in the select...)
    var query = (from items in results select items.filterName.ToString()).Distinct();

    // Populate the ddl (not complete code...)
    foreach (var item in query)
    {
        ddl.Items.Add(item...);
    }
}
```

My problem is that I find plenty of documentation on how to modify the WHERE or GROUP BY or any other parts of linq statements at run-time. I just don't find any on how to change dynamically the field I want to retrieve.

Is there an easy way to do this? Thank you.
Yipi

Edit:

```
List<Orders> results = OrdersService.GetOrders();

public class Orders
{
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime? Day
    [DataMember]
    public int? Order
    [DataMember]
    public int? Product
    [DataMember]
    public int? Cost
    [DataMember]
    public int? Price
    [DataMember]
    public int? Client
    [DataMember]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

```
var query = "....";
query = query.Select("PropName");
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am not at liberty to use other libraries. Thank you.

Comment: Worked so well I could present a business case and get the authorization to use it - tanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem by building the lambda expression by hand.

The query you currently use can be changed to use method chains syntax and will then look like this:

```
var query = results.Select(item => item.<filterName>.ToString()).Distinct();
```

Now we need to create the lambda expression that is passed to `Distinct` ourselves.

This can be achieved using the following method:

```
Expression<Func<YourResultType, string>> CreateExpression(string propertyName)
{
    var itemExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(YourResultType), "item");
    var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(itemExpression, propertyName);
    var toStringExpression = Expression.Call(propertyExpression,
                                             "ToString", null);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<YourResultType, string>>(toStringExpression, 
                                                           itemExpression);
}
```

Now we can change the query to this:

```
var query = results.Select(CreateExpression(filterName)).Distinct();
```

Please note that you need to change `YourResultType` to the type of the instances in your `results` variable. Also, if you are not querying a database but an in memory list, you need to change the query to this:

```
var query = results.Select(CreateExpression(filterName).Compile()).Distinct();
```

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with expression trees - the object 'results' is a simple List<Orders>. When using your code I get errors immediately as I type it. Any pointer of docs I should look at? Thanks.

Comment: If you tell me *which* errors you are getting, I might be able to help.

Comment: Sorry - This is what I see: .....................System.Collections.Generic.List<MYTYPEHERE>' does not contain a definition for 'Distinct' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Distinct<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments..............Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Func<MYTYPEHERE,string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<MYTYPEHERE>'.......

Comment: @yipiha: Oh my... I am sorry. The overload I tried to use here doesn't exist. I fixed the code, please check

Comment: It compiles but I get this at run-time: Instance property 'Client' is not defined for type 'MYTYPEHERE'... with none of the attributes defined for the class Orders.

Comment: @yipiha: I am not sure I understand your comment, especially the second part about "class Orders". Could you please rephrase it? About the error: Does your class have a public property `Client`?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details - Yes my class has a public property Client - the error occurs whatever the property I use (they are of different data types) - anything you want me to try? I am totally out of my depth now...

Comment: @yipiha: OK, just to be sure we are talking about the same thing here: Please update your question with these details: (1) Please show how `results` is declared, especially of which type it is. (2) Please show the definition of the class that is in the `results` list.

Comment: @yipiha: That code isn't even close to compilable... Please fix

Comment: Right - going for dynamic.cs solved the problem immediately and adding some IEumerable to it made it work with my data without a need for .AsQueryable() - thank you for your help.